# How to Get Commit-interval or numbers of error line and processed lines in ProcessorLister in Spring Batch?

Tags: spring-batch

I'm new to programming from Japan.
As I wrote the title, how can I get commit-interval or or numbers of error line and numbers of all processed line in a lister class that implements ProcessorLister in Spring Batch?

ProcessListener implements ProcessorListener 
 `

```
@Override
public void afterProcess(T item, S result) {
  //Do nothing
}

@Override
public void onProcessError(T item, Exception e) {
    setSkipCount(skipCount + Cons.number.ONE);
        toInt = Integer.valueOf(lineCount);
        int allLines = toInt + skipCount - Cons.number.ONE;
        logger.info("NumbersOfErrorLine :" + allLines);
        logger.info("NumbersOfSkipCount :" + skipCount);
    setLineCount(Cons.number.ZERO);
}`
```

I tried to count numbers of error line and also all numbers of processed line but counting will be started by zero after commit.

I mean if I set commit-interval of 10, counting will be succeeded at first but counting will be started by zero again. I want the counting will count from 11.

I'm apologise that I cannot explain well but I hope someone answer or give me advise.

Thanks for reading.